# java "launch" returns "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: java, class, javafx

when i try to run my java file with javafx from command prompt im returned with a error, the error says the problem of the code is coming from a java launch command which i dont know how to fix. Please give a fix.
the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main1
        at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:314)
        at Main1.main(Main1.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main1
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:488)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:302)
        at Main1.main(Main1.java:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:421)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:192)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;  

public class Main1 extends Application {
   
  
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        try {
   
          
            stage.setTitle("Fierce Pcs");
   
          
            WebView w = new WebView();
   
           
            WebEngine e = w.getEngine();
   
          
            e.load("https://www.example.com/");
            stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png")));
           
            Scene scene = new Scene(w, w.getPrefWidth(), 
                                     w.getPrefHeight());
   
          
            stage.setScene(scene);
   
            stage.show();
        }
   
        catch (Exception e) {
   
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
   
  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
   
       
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

the command which i give the command prompt:

```
java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.fxml,javafx.web C:\Users\example\OneDrive\Desktop\Main1.java
```

Comment: @Antoniossss since Java 11 you can: https://openjdk.org/jeps/330

Comment: okayy :(  didnt know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    launch(Main1.class, args);
```

Or stay with `launch(args)` and compile your Main1.java to Main1.class and run (i suppose this is the default (none) package):

```
     javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.fxml,javafx.web Main1.java
     java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.fxml,javafx.web Main1
```